# How to disable auto hide/show toolbar in CKEDITOR inline

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

CKEDITOR inline shows/hide the toolbar when focusing or blurring the DOM element with content `contenteditable="true"`.

For example if a user click on a background of the page, CKEDITOR hide the toolbar.

I need instead show always the toolbar and disable any auto show/hide feature.

Any way how to achieve it?

http://jsfiddle.net/vdRYL/28/

```
<script src="//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.5.3/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>
Default behaviour: 
<div id="first" contenteditable="true">Click me</div>
<br>
```

I have tried

```
CKEDITOR.inline(this._cloneDom.id, { startupFocus: false });
```

but with no success

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I did and it seem to be working:

```
// in config I have set the recommended value:
config.startupFocus = true;

// load the editor
var instance = CKEDITOR.inline(element.id, {
    // ... load config
});

// this works to prevent hiding of the editor, I don't know yet if this breaks anything, 
// but seems to be working fine
instance.on('blur',function(){
   return false;
});


// and because the startupFocus property triggers focus on each element that has the editor
// I scroll the document to the top on the event when editor is ready
instance.on("instanceReady", function(){
     document.body.scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

We can hide and show toolbar. I have achieved this functionality using following way:

Open `ckeditor.js` file. And paste below code at the end of the file

```
$(document).ready(function () {  
   CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function (ev) {  
      document.getElementById(ev.editor.id + '_top').style.display = 'none';  


      ev.editor.on('focus', function (e) {  
         document.getElementById(ev.editor.id + '_top').style.display = 'block';  

      });  
      ev.editor.on('blur', function (e) {  
         document.getElementById(ev.editor.id + '_top').style.display = 'none';  

      });  
   });  
});
```